# I want to remove text between fifth and sixth occurrence of "/"

Tags: php, wordpress

This is url stored in variable

https://photoland2.etrafficgroup.com.au/frames-and-albums/frames/wooden-frames/106-a3-297-x-42cm-2/product/555-black-wooden-frame-with-gold-stripe-a3-42x29-7cm-size-1-7cm-wide/

I want to remove text between fifth and sixth occurrence of  "/" (106-a3-297-x-42cm-2) and one /

Output should look like this:

https://photoland2.etrafficgroup.com.au/frames-and-albums/frames/wooden-frames/product/555-black-wooden-frame-with-gold-stripe-a3-42x29-7cm-size-1-7cm-wide/

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  an do it by many ways,. One way to achieve this way using `parse_url()`,

```
  <?php
  $url = 'https://photoland2.etrafficgroup.com.au/frames-and-albums/frames/wooden-frames/106-a3-297-x-42cm-2/product/555-black-wooden-frame-with-gold-stripe-a3-42x29-7cm-size-1-7cm-wide/';
  $initial = parse_url($url);
  $result = array_filter(explode('/',parse_url($url)['path']));
  unset($result[4]);
  $filtered = implode('/',$result);
  echo $initial['scheme'].'://'.$initial['host'].'/'.$filtered.'/';
  ?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/60rZB

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

```
<?php
$urlString = 'https://photoland2.etrafficgroup.com.au/frames-and-albums/frames/wooden-frames/106-a3-297-x-42cm-2/product/555-black-wooden-frame-with-gold-stripe-a3-42x29-7cm-size-1-7cm-wide/';
$arrayString = explode('/', $urlString, 8);
$result = str_replace('/'.$arrayString[6], '', $urlString);
echo $result;
?>
```